# Android services in separate file don't work

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-service

I'm trying to build my first android widget - its a simple icon, on which when i click somethings hapens - on "something" I'm using service. Everything goes fine, but i have a little problem, which I don't understand. This works fine:

```
CLASS MYWIDGET.JAVA
------------------------------------------------
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() == null) context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
    else super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
}

public static class UpdateService extends IntentService {

    public UpdateService() {
        super("MyWidget$UpdateService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        ComponentName me = new ComponentName(this, MyWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        manager.updateAppWidget(me, buildUpdate(this));
    }

    private RemoteViews buildUpdate (Context context) {
        // i'm doing something here
    }
}
```

}

but when i extract UpdateService to separate file it doesn't work:

```
CLASS MYWIDGET.JAVA
------------------------------------------------
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() == null) context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
    else super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
}
```

}

```
CLASS UPDATESERVICE.JAVA
-------------------------------
public class UpdateService extends IntentService {

    public UpdateService() {
        super("UpdateService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        ComponentName me = new ComponentName(this, MyWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        manager.updateAppWidget(me, buildUpdate(this));
    }

    private RemoteViews buildUpdate (Context context) {
        // i'm doing something here
    }
}
```

}

This version doesnt work - when i click on widget icon, no method in update service is never called. Where should be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move or rename the service class, you will need to reflect this change in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: yeah, i noticed this in same moment u wrote ;) What a stupid mistake...I should have more breaks during work ;) thx, problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<service android:name=".UpdateService" />
```

to your manifest.xml (maybe u'll have to set the right package name before the name itself)